# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:5) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server

---

I have this error code . 
i think this error is caused by webpack.config.js
I have studied many sources but could not get results

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:5)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    |  */
    | /*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
    | html {
    |   font-family: sans-serif;
    |   -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
     @ ./index.js 21:0-43
     @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./index.js
```

---

my webpack.config.js . 
I have made arrangements here. but again I got an error. 
how can i overcome this error

```
         var webpack = require('webpack');
        var path = require('path');

        var parentDir = path.join(__dirname, '../');

        module.exports = {
            entry: [
                path.join(parentDir, 'index.js')
            ],
            module: {
                loaders: [{
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                        loader: 'babel-loader'
                    },{
                        test: /\.less$/,
                        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loder", "less-loader"]
                    }
                ]
            },
            output: {
                path: parentDir + '/dist',
                filename: 'bundle.js'
            },
            devServer: {
                contentBase: parentDir,
                historyApiFallback: true
            }
        }
```

---

index.js like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import AppRoutes from './routes';
import store from './store';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

ReactDOM.render(

<Provider store={store}>

 <AppRoutes />

 </Provider>,
 document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you need to add some more configuration to your `css-loader`.

Currently, you have this for your less files:

```
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "less-loader"]
}
```

Like the error message mentions, you need to configure a loader for `css` files in addition to `less`. Try this:

```
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "less-loader"]
}, {
  test: /\.css$/,
  loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
}
```